# Shapefile with overlapping polygons: calculate average values

Tags: gis, postgis, shapefile, polygons, arcmap

I have a very big polygon shapefile with hundreds of features, often overlapping each other. Each of these features has a value stored in the attribute table. I simply need to calculate the average values in the areas where they overlap.
I can imagine that this task requires several intricate steps: I was wondering if there is a straightforward methodology.
I’m open to every kind of suggestion, I can use ArcMap, QGis, arcpy scripts, PostGis, GDAL… I just need ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few attempts, I found a solution by rasterising all the features singularly and then performing cell statistics in order to calculate the average. 
See below the script I wrote, please do not hesitate to comment and improve it!
Thanks!

```
    #This script processes a shapefile of snow persistence (area of interest: Afghanistan).
    #the input shapefile represents a month of snow cover and contains several features.
    #each feature represents a particular day and a particular snow persistence (low,medium,high,nodata)
    #these features are polygons multiparts, often overlapping.
    #a feature of a particular day can overlap a feature of another one, but features of the same day and with
    #different snow persistence can not overlap each other.
    #(potentially, each shapefile contains 31*4 feature).
    #the script takes the features singularly and exports each feature in a temporary shapefile
    #which contains only one feature.
    #Then, each feature is converted to raster, and after
    #a logical conditional expression gives a value to the pixel according the intensity (high=3,medium=2,low=1,nodata=skipped).
    #Finally, all these rasters are summed and divided by the number of days, in order to
    #calculate an average value.
    #The result is a raster with the average snow persistence in a particular month.
    #This output raster ranges from 0 (no snow) to 3 (persistent snow for the whole month)
    #and values outside this range should be considered as small errors in pixel overlapping.
    #This script needs a particular folder structure. The folder C:\TEMP\Afgh_snow_cover contains 3 subfolders
    #input, temp and outputs. The script takes care automatically of the cleaning of temporary data


    import arcpy, numpy, os
    from arcpy.sa import *
    from arcpy import env

    #function for finding unique values of a field in a FC
    def unique_values_in_table(table, field):
            data = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(table, [field])
            return numpy.unique(data[field])

    #check extensions
    try:
        if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
            arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
        else:
            # Raise a custom exception
            #
            raise LicenseError
    except LicenseError:
        print "spatial Analyst license is unavailable"  
    except:
        print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
    finally:
        # Check in the 3D Analyst extension
        #
        arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")

    # parameters and environment
    temp_folder = r"C:\TEMP\Afgh_snow_cover\temp_rasters"
    output_folder = r"C:\TEMP\Afgh_snow_cover\output_rasters"
    env.workspace = temp_folder
    unique_field = "FID"
    field_Date = "DATE"
    field_Type = "Type"
    cellSize = 0.02


    fc = r"C:\TEMP\Afgh_snow_cover\input_shapefiles\snow_cover_Dec2007.shp"

    stat_output_name = fc[-11:-4] + ".tif"

    #print stat_output_name
    arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF"

    #find all the uniquesID of the FC
    uniqueIDs = unique_values_in_table(fc, "FID")

    #make layer for selecting
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (fc, "lyr")
    #uniqueIDs = uniqueIDs[-5:]
    totFeatures = len(uniqueIDs)
    #for each feature, get the date and the type of snow persistence(type can be high, medium, low and nodata)
    for i in uniqueIDs:
        SC = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
        for row in SC:
            if row.getValue(unique_field) == i:
                datestring = row.getValue(field_Date)
                typestring = row.getValue(field_Type)

        month = str(datestring.month)
        day = str(datestring.day)
        year = str(datestring.year)

    #format month and year string
        if len(month) == 1:
            month = '0' + month

        if len(day) == 1:
            day = '0' + day

    #convert snow persistence to numerical value
        if typestring == 'high':
            typestring2 = 3
        if typestring == 'medium':
            typestring2 = 2
        if typestring == 'low':
            typestring2 = 1
        if typestring == 'nodata':
            typestring2 = 0
    #skip the NoData features, and repeat the following for each feature (a feature is a day and a persistence value)
        if typestring2 > 0:
                #create expression for selecting the feature
                expression = ' "FID" = ' + str(i) + ' '
                #select the feature
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
                #create 
                #outFeatureClass = os.path.join(temp_folder, ("M_Y_" + str(i)))
                #create faeture class name, writing the snow persistence value at the end of the name
                outFeatureClass = "Afg_" + str(year) + str(month) + str(day) + "_" + str(typestring2) + '.shp'
                #export the feature
                arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("lyr", temp_folder, outFeatureClass)
                print "exported FID " + str(i) + " \ " + str(totFeatures)
                #create name of the raster and convert the newly created feature to raster
                outRaster = outFeatureClass[4:-4] + ".tif"
                arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion(outFeatureClass, field_Type, outRaster, cellSize)
                #remove the temporary fc
                arcpy.Delete_management(outFeatureClass)
        del SC, row
    #now many rasters are created, representing the snow persistence types of each day. 
    #list all the rasters created 
    rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "All")
    print rasterList

    #now the rasters have values 1 and 0. the following loop will
    #perform CON expressions in order to assign the value of snow persistence
    for i in rasterList:
            print i + ":"
            inRaster = Raster(i)
            #set the value of snow persistence, stored in the raster name
            value_to_set = i[-5]
            inTrueRaster = int(value_to_set)
            inFalseConstant = 0
            whereClause = "Value > 0"


            # Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
            arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
            print 'Executing CON expression and deleting input'
            # Execute Con , in order to assign to each pixel the value of snow persistence
            print str(inTrueRaster)
            try:
                    outCon = Con(inRaster, inTrueRaster, inFalseConstant, whereClause)
            except:
                    print 'CON expression failed (probably empty raster!)'

            nameoutput = i[:-4] + "_c.tif"
            outCon.save(nameoutput)
            #delete the temp rasters with values 0 and 1
            arcpy.Delete_management(i)
    #list the raster with values of snow persistence
    rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("*_c.tif", "All")
    #sum the rasters
    print "Caclulating SUM"
    outCellStats = CellStatistics(rasterList, "SUM", "DATA")
    #calculate the number of days (num of rasters/3)
    print "Calculating day ratio"
    num_of_rasters = len(rasterList)
    print 'Num of rasters : ' + str(num_of_rasters)
    num_of_days = num_of_rasters / 3
    print 'Num of days : ' + str(num_of_days)
    #in order to store decimal values, multiplicate the raster by 1000 before dividing
    outCellStats = outCellStats * 1000 / num_of_days
    #save the output raster
    print "saving output " + stat_output_name
    stat_output_name = os.path.join(output_folder,stat_output_name)
    outCellStats.save(stat_output_name)
    #delete the remaining temporary rasters
    print "deleting CON rasters"
    for i in rasterList:
            print "deleting " + i
            arcpy.Delete_management(i)
    arcpy.Delete_management("lyr")
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [Union tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000s000000) from ArcGIS. It will create new polygons where the polygons overlap. In order to keep the attributes from both polygons, add your polygon shapefile twice as input and use ALL as join_attributes parameter.This creates also polygons intersecting with themselves, you can select and delete them easily as they have the same FIDs. Then just add a new field to the attribute table and calculate it based on the two original value fields from the input polygons. 
This can be done in a script or directly with the toolbox's tools.

Comment: I think that this would work only if there are 2 layers of overlapping polygons. In my case, I have many layers of overlapping polygons within the same shapefile. 
I have tried this solution anyway, but due to the size of the input shapefile (more than 200 MB due to large extent and high resolution), it is not possible to make such operation.
I have find a final solution by rasterising all the features singularly and then performing cell statistics in order to calculate the average. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you rasterize your polygons into multiple layers, each pixel could contain your attribute value. Then merge the layers by averaging the attribute values?

Comment: Right! That is exactly what I did and it works! (see the python code I have posted). Thanks!

Comment: @Andreampa, please flag my answer as an answer and upvote it if it was good for you.

Comment: I would have done it already, if only I had enough credit... i'm a new user!